# Hide / Show Ext.js compositefield with label in Ext.js 3.4

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I`m trying to show/hide an ext.js (xtype:"compositefield") with an listener from a combo. All works well, except the composite field's Label won't hide. How do I select the whole composite field DOM element so i can use .hide()/.show() on it ?

the code for compositefield:

```
xtype: 'compositefield',
                   labelStyle: 'width: 60px',
                   fieldLabel: 'Player 1',
                   id: "player_1_fields",
                   msgTarget: 'under',
                   items:[
                       {xtype: 'displayfield', value: 'Name',margins: '3 5 0 22'},
                       {xtype: 'textfield', name: 'props_name_1', width: 135},
                       {xtype: 'displayfield', value: 'Score',margins: '3 5 0 0'},
                       {xtype: 'numberfield', name: 'props_score_n1', width: 35}
                   ]
```

the code for listener:

```
listeners: {
                                    select: function(combo, record, index) {
                                     if ( combo.getValue() == "2" ) 
                                                {
                                                Ext.getCmp("player_1_fields").getEl().hide();

                                                }
                                            else
                                                {
                                                Ext.getCmp("player_1_fields").getEl().show();

                                                }
                                    }
                                  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
select: function(combo, record, index) {
    if ( combo.getValue() == "2" ) {
            Ext.getCmp("player_1_fields").getEl().up('.x-form-composite').hide();
    } else {
            Ext.getCmp("player_1_fields").getEl().up('.x-form-composite').show();
    }
}
```

Up should find parent with a specific class (and you want that to be ExtJs class for whole form item).

Comment: Nope, it is in 3.4 too, it is even in 2.1 docs. Here is [link to Element.up method in ExtJs 3.4](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-up)

Comment: sorry fast & wrong assumption, I got : TypeError: Ext.getCmpup("..").up is not a function.  Up must be used on the element, not on getCmp. ( Ext.getCmp("player_1_fields").getEl().up('.x-form-item').hide() ). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why don't just use the setVisible function of the CompositeField ?

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-method-setVisible

Comment: @rockskull Because `setVisible` on component it self wont hide its label, counterintuitive I agree, but I think it is like that because label rendering is done inside layout manager, so technically label is not part of component itself.